# Good webapp for checking availability of domain names?

Tags: webapp-rec, domain

Is there an web/AJAX app that enables me to check availability of domain names under all top level domains? It would be a plus if it also could recommend similar domain names or have other innovative features.

Please make sure that the solution you provide is safe (e.g. it isn't a [domain front running scam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_front_running)), or if it is, please let people know about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use [Domize](https://domize.com/) which is simple and quick, they also have a mobile version i believe.

They have quite a variety of TLDs to search:

> [domize1 http://cl.ly/1ciZ/Screen_shot_2010-07-11_at_17.26.48.png](http://cl.ly/1ciZ/Screen_shot_2010-07-11_at_17.26.48.png)

And some interesting search options:

> [domize2 http://cl.ly/1cQA/Screen_shot_2010-07-11_at_17.28.09.png](http://cl.ly/1cQA/Screen_shot_2010-07-11_at_17.28.09.png)

Answer (score 4):

I love [domai.nr](http://domai.nr) for this sort of thing. Doesn't search *all* TLD's, but checks availability and recommends similar/abbreviated names across TLD's. Not perfect, but the best I've used.

Answer (score 4):

How did no one suggest http://ajaxwhois.com? By far the best/fastest option.

Comment: Looks very good, but only support a very limited subset of domains. Although, for .comish names it's a good option. Upvote from me.

Comment: definitely fastest, even though least option driven. upvote

Comment: Any proof that it's not a front runner?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to check for **domain names on all TLDs** as you say in your question, don't go past [iWantMyName](http://iwantmyname.com/) which **searches over 80 extensions** (as far as I can tell - that figure does include things like .co.uk as well though).

If you are primarily looking for the **innovative features and name suggestions**, as you say in your question, then check out all of these - and apologies for the plain text, I can't insert more than one hyperlink at my current rep level :(

- www.nameboy.com
- www.bustaname.com
- www.domaintyper.com *(also suggested by @Grant Palin)*
- www.domai.nr *(also suggested by @tsondermann, and the site I use the
  most for lookups)*
- www.nxdom.com
- www.dotomator.com

Answer (score 2):

The web app [Wordoid.com](http://wordoid.com) is superb for name ideas, as well as checking on the availability of .com and .net domains.  It lets you specify a starting word, then builds up prefixes and/or suffices around that word, checking for "naturalness" against up to 5 languages (English, Spanish, French, Italian, German).  You can also specify the maximum word length.  Finally, it tells you the approximate current search hits for the suggested names; for building a new brand, this can be crucial, as you'll want to zoom in on words that have few or no current search hits.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Instant domain search](http://instantdomainsearch.com/). Instant results! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://gandi.net - their domain lookup is decent, and they don't try to upsell you like so many others.

For brainstorming domains, http://domai.nr/ are pretty good and their site is pretty slick too.

Answer (score 0):

[Who.is](http://who.is/) can do that, just type the keyword in without the TLD.

Answer (score 0):

[Namechecklist.com](http://www.namechecklist.com/) is a tool that is launched last week which even checks the chosen name on social networks and gives feedback on how unique it is via google results.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Domain Lookup" on [whois.net](http://www.whois.net).

Answer (score 0):

I've toyed with [DomainTyper](http://domaintyper.com/) before. It suggests domain "hacks" based on what you type in. It also seems to support quite a variety of TLDs.